# iOS8 app crashes on Xcode6.0.1 using HealthKit

Tags: ios8, xcode6, healthkit

Im actually trying to convert Apple's sample code to swift.

I created an app and an APPID for it in the devcenter.  I checked the entitlement for HealthKit (the ones for IAP & GC are greyed and checked automatically).

When the provisioning profile I create for it is downloaded to Xcode and I go into Preferences in Xcode and look at my account's provisioning profiles I can see the name of the profile plus the expiration date and then there are some icons for entitlements.  But the provisioning profile I created with HealthKit doesnt have any icon for it, just the 2 default ones, is this normal:

[image: xcode preferences]

because for some reason the app crashes upon requesting authorization with this error:

2014-10-02 12:16:13.241 SwimFit[549:8824] -[__NSCFConstantString _allowAuthorizationForSharingWithEntitlements:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107dc1ce0
2014-10-02 12:16:13.251 SwimFit[549:8824] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _allowAuthorizationForSharingWithEntitlements:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107dc1ce0'

If I try to run it on the device I get this:

[image: on device]

I have created:

1. AppId for my app
2. Activated that AppID for HealthKit
3. Created Dev provisioning profile for that AppID
4. Activated HealthKit Capabilities in General
5. I see the entitlements.plist is created with com.apple.developer.healthkit = yes
6. The info.plist does have the healthkit value for required capabilities

The only weird thing I did this time and I used to do differently for other apps is that when I clicked on build/run a some point, I let Xcode create an AppID and I get this from devcenter...i cant upload the image but basically all my previous AppIDs are named after the app.  This one because its made by xcode is named: Xcode iOS App ID com santiapps SwimFit but its bundle identifier is correct at: com.santiapps.SwimFit.  And so is the dev profile: iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.santiapps.SwimFit and its the one in my Build Settings.  Originally I had SwimFit because that was the name of the app so Xcode created an automatic AppID for it with a ProvProfile for it as well.  I then thought maybe I should create the appID and provprofile so I did it manually and tried calling it SwimFit2.  Both give the same error.

What else could I be missing?

Here is the code:

```
//1. Add healthstore property

    var healthStore: HKHealthStore? //error if not optionally unwrapped
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        //2.  Ask for permissions

        if (HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() == true) {
            self.healthStore = HKHealthStore() //needs to be var for it to work?
            var writeDataTypes = self.dataTypesToWrite()
            var readDataTypes = self.dataTypesToRead()
            self.healthStore!.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(writeDataTypes, readTypes: readDataTypes, completion: { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (!success) {
                        NSLog("You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: %@. If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.", error)
                    return
                    } else {
                        NSLog("success")
                    }
                // Handle success in your app here.
                self.setupHealthStoreForTabBarControllers()
            })
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here is a link with a screen capture: http://youtu.be/BBagkNTpfQA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same crash yesterday. The problem is that you put the wrong data type (*NSString*) for the data types into the method.

The *requestAuthorizationToShareTypes* method requires you to pass a set of **HKBaseType** objects, in my case **HKQuantityType** objects.

So instead of:

```
[_healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex]
                                             readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:inputDataTypes]
                                            completion:
```

Use this one:

```
HKQuantityType* type = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex];
[_healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:type]
                                             readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:inputDataTypes]
                                            completion:
```